# PHPWord - How to Convert HTML to Docx?

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

How do I convert this unclean html tag into word document?
I am totally lost here, I don't know what I am doing, my goal is just to covert this html into word document, doesn't need to be fancy or accurate, I just want it to display the layout and its contents, styling can be ignored as well.
My code generates a doc file but cannot be opened due to problem found in the contents.

```
    $html = "<h3>Restaurant Brands</h3>
            <ul class='prodoplist'>
                <li>BJ's Restaurant &amp; Brewery</li>
                <li>BJ's Restaurant &amp; Brewhouse</li>
                <li>BJ's Pizza &amp; Grill</li>
                <li>BJ's Grill</li>
            </ul>
            <p><strong>Selected Menu Items</strong>
                <br>Shareable Appetizers
                <br>BJ's Snacks &amp; Small Bites
                <br>Lunch Specials
                <br>Sandwiches and Tacos
                <br>Handcrafted Burgers
                <br>Housemade Soups &amp; Salads
                <br>Starter Salads
                <br>Garden Fresh Specialty Salads
                <br>Beverages
                <br>Handcrafted Beers
                <br>Cocktails and Wine
                <br>Pizza
                <br>Pasta favorites
            </p>";


 $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
 $phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(10);
 $phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Calibri');
 $phpWord->setDefaultParagraphStyle(
 array(
        'spaceAfter' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pointToTwip(0))
 );
 $metaDataSection = $phpWord->addSection();
 $table = $metaDataSection->addTable('Test');

 $breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");  
 $text = str_replace($breaks, "<br/>", $html); 
 $text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE',$text);
 $text = "<html>". $text . "</html>";
 $table->addRow();
 $cell = $table->addCell(10000); \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($cell, $text); 
 $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
```

Comment: @Cid my definition of unclean HTML is <br> or <p> might not have closing tag or some other HTML Tags might not have proper closing tag,

it also doesn't have body, head and title tag

Comment: @Cid I have updated my question, my question will be how to convert the html I have to docx, I am encountering an error upon opening the generated doc file, it says the content is not supported